# Gradle: Execution failed for task ':MyPackage:dexDefaultFlavorDebug'

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm getting this error when I add the android support libraries in my build file. I've tried adding compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.0', compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:19.0.0' and compile 'com.google.android:support-v4:r7'.

Still I get the same error. I've also tried to add the support-lib jar and run. Nothing works. Please help. I"m totally stuck. :(

```
Gradle: Execution failed for task ':MyPackage:dexDefaultFlavorDebug'.
```

> Could not call IncrementalTask.taskAction() on task ':MyPackage:dexDefaultFlavorDebug'

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your build.gradle.

Comment: Run your build from the command line. That will give you more information, and if you use the --info and --stacktrace options, you'll get more information yet. If you can't figure it out from that, post the results in your question.